# Apache common codec - Why Hex.encode() isn't static?

Tags: java, hex, apache-commons-codec

[Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) have many static encode methods returning byte[] as

```
Base64.encodeBase64(stringToEncode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
```

Also [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) using static `getInstance` to encode/digest

But [Hex](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) doesn't, it have only instance method [encode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encode-byte:A-) which requires to create an instance

```
new Hex().encode(stringToEncode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
```

Is there a reason I need to create instance to get byte array or is there a better way?

I currently don't think adding `getBytes()` is a good idea, for example

```
Hex.encodeHexString(stringToEncode).getBytes()
```

Comment: Why do you need them as bytes? It makes sense that `encodeHex` returns `char[]`, because the result is numbers and letters. Converting those to bytes seems highly unnecessary.

Comment: @kayaman I want to create a generic encoding method and other methods returns `bytes[]`

Comment: @kayaman Can I suggest adding static method to library as enhancement?

Comment: I don't see why not. You can even implement it yourself and submit it to them as a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no static method for you to use, but the class is thread-safe so you can just create an instance of it and keep it around.

It's a common idiom with some classes like `ObjectMapper` or formatting objects for example. Of course they usually have more internal state than `Hex` needs, so maybe this was a design oversight.

I believe the reason for these being instance methods is that the constructor takes a `Charset`, which is required for converting chars to bytes. The alternative would've been to pass it as a parameter in a static method. Both could be implemented of course.